# Calculate a determinant related to permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $ M$ be  a  permutation $n \times n $ matrix and $[\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \ldots,\lambda_n]$ be the cycle type of the corresponding permutation, i.e. $ \lambda_i$ is  the number of  cycles of  the lenght $i$.

How to prove that 
$$
\det(I \pm M \cdot z)=\prod_i (1 \pm z^i)^{\lambda_i}?
$$
Or  give me a link to a proof.
Thanks.

**Edit.**

$z$ is formal variable.

Comment: Is $z\in \mathbb{F}^n$?

Comment: no, $z$ is just a formal letter

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by a letter? What is $z^i$?

Comment: Ok, $z$ is a formal variable, like as avariable in characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your permutation is a product of disjoint cycles, so $M$ is block diagonalized into corresponding matrices (which have size $i$ and have ones on the superdiagonal and on the lower left hand corner). So, all you need to show is that the characteristic polynomial of a cycle matrix has the right form. But that follows immediately from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem .

Comment: But characteristic polynomial has the form $\det(M-z \cdot I)$  not $\det(I \pm M \cdot z)$. What is the relation for these determinants?

Comment: @Leox let $z=1/u,$ and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, yes..I see..But it works for the case $\det(I-M\cdot z)$. For $\det(I+M\cdot z)$  I cant  just  put $z=-1/u$.

Comment: @Leox why not??

Comment: since $(1-z^2)$ sends   to  $1-(1/u)^2$ but I need $1+(1/u)^2$. How to get reguired "+"?

Comment: @leox just try it and see.

Comment: I understood now. Thank you!